# How to turn arbitrary function to polinomial series in Mathematica?

Tags: series-expansion

Can I turn any multivariate function into polinomial series in *Mathematica*?

Suppose I have a function

```
Fwd[x_, α_] := x (1/Sin[Pi x/2])^α
```

and wish to express it with a formula, consisting only of multiplications and summations. Is it possible?

If I apply

```
Normal[Series[Fwd[x, α], {x, 0, 3}, {α, 0, 3}]]
```

I get complex formula

[image]

which contains `Log` function. Why?

Answer (score 3):

You get log because:

```
Fwd[x_,\[Alpha]_]:=x (1/Sin[Pi x/2])^\[Alpha] = x* Exp[\[Alpha]*Log[1/Sin[Pi x/2]]]
```

and the log is from the expansion with respect to alpha.